# User and Dashboard relationship

Tags: apex, soql

I want to setup User and Dashboard relationship following is my query.

```sql
SELECT 
    Title, 
    FolderName, 
    LastViewedDate, 
    Description, 
    RunningUserId, 
    DeveloperName, 
    CreatedById.User.Name 
FROM Dashboard 
USING SCOPE allPrivate
```

I want `Name` from `CreatedbyId` but it gives me an error. Can someone take a look into this?

Comment: did you try CreatedBy.Name?

Comment: Thanks this works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreatedBy.Name` gives the Name of the User

`CreatedById` is for the Id of the user.

Your query becomes

```
select Title, CreatedBy.Name FROM Dashboard
```